# Hikvision cctv video time issue

Tags: video, dvr, cctv, bug-tracking

I extracted video from hikvision nvr, on these videos sometimes time gets skipped 3 minutes and goes back 3 minutes, although there is no frame skipping, videos plays smooth. Why this happens?

Comment: In my experience, DVR/NVR often create bad video indexes. Is the output in AVI?

Comment: No, videos was extracted in mp4 format on usb flash stick.

Comment: Does the issue happen if you extract from iVMS or HikConnect?

Comment: Directly extracting from nvr through usb port.

Comment: Try extracting a video **without** converting it to MP4. Then use the Format Converter here to convert it to mp4: :https://ca.hikvision.com/en/support-resources/downloads/tools  If it doesn't skip then the internal MP4 conversion isn't doing it correctly.